# Reactjs: Multiple actions call with pagination make page slow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have problem with pager click to re-render list users. Please check on my logic below

Firstly, I list all users by calling an action is ListUsersAction like this:

```
const ListUsers = props => {
  useEffect(() => {
      var resPerPage = configList.users.resPerPage;
      props.ListUsersAction(resPerPage, 1);
  },[]);
  .....
  .....
}
```

I used a reducer `listUsersReducer` to store users. I call it like that:

```
if (props.listUsersReducer.thanhvien.length > 0) {
    const users = props.listUsersReducer.thanhvien;

    //Then render all user here.
    users.map((user)=>....);

    //I make a pagination to change users list by click on each page.
    <Pagination datasend={datasend} />
}
```

I has no problem from first load. And problem occur when I click 6-7 times on pagination to call `LoadUsersAction`. It start slowly and make page lag.

Action called every time click page change.
[image]

I do not know anything I made wrong. Can you help me to check it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is solved. It is not related to redux. It is store.subscribe render multiple times. Just add it in useEffect and it is solved.